# URI related Whitelist error in Phonegap for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, cordova, uri, whitelist, cordova-2.0.0

```
ERROR whitelist rejection: url='http://api.some_host-name.country_code/some_thing.json'
```

This is the format of the URI i am using to get feeds in json format.

please tell me how to add it to my External Host Array in the cordova.plist
I have tried adding
    *,
    *.*,
    *.some_host_name.com
    *.some_host_name.country_code
    *.some_host_name.country_code/*

etc. etc.
But nothing seems to work and all I get is just the UI loaded on screen.
Kindly help me with this thing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you add the `*` entry to the External Host Array and didn't have success??

Comment: yup I added * but it still gave me this error.

Comment: And after that cleaned and built your project again?

Comment: I restarted my mac and did a reset to the simulator and it did the trick. But I was still thinking of something that is a bit more secure then plain asterisk(*). Cz I have read that it in not the most secure way of implementing this.

Comment: No, of course it isn't. If you can delimit the URL's you're gonna call, allow just those ones. So, was the clean and build thing what fixed the issue? Should I post it as an answer?

Comment: Sure, go ahead n post it as an answer. But its really ill logical of why after a clean n build it runs properly. In fact not just a clean n build, I had to reset my simulator and restart my mac. N plz tell me how do i put my URI into the external links array? i mean what format should i use? As this will also clear doubts for others.

Comment: Yep, sometimes even the JavasCript doesn't get refreshed if I don't clean and build. Are you using Xcode?

Comment: Yes I am Using Xcode for doing it. N also cordova is poorly documented for now. I just hope it gets better with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes if you don't clean and rebuild the project there are some issues, so I would recommend to clean first.

To add new records to the whitelist, if you are using Xcode, fetch the Cordova.plist in the working tree and select it. Open the `ExternalHosts` dropdown list and press the `+` sign that will show up and it will add a new record, that you can fill with your server name, wildcard or whatever you need.